# Evaluate subscription callback at time observable is created

Tags: angular, observable

I have a Reactive Form in which it appears the function inside the following subscription evaluates `itm["value"].length-1` at the time the observable emits data (and calls the subscription function).

```
      this.formCtls[controlName] = new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});
      this.userForm.addControl(controlName, this.formCtls[controlName]);
      this.formCtls[controlName].valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
        itm["value"][itm["value"].length-1]=val;
        this.renderDataArray();
      });
```

However I want the subscription callback function expression `itm["value"].length-1` to be evaluated at the time the observable/(FormControl) is created.

For instance, at the time the form control is created, `itm["value"].length` might only be `2`, but at the time the Observable emits `itm["value"].length` may be `6` or `7` or any other number. How can I (programmatically) "hardwire" the `2` (or equivalent) into the subscription callback?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the answer below now. It worked in my code, but I'm not sure why it worked. I will re-evaluate this provisional answer and post an update. In the meantime, I'd be very grateful for any input from an expert as I'm a bit confused and lost amongst these Observables. . .

```
this.formCtls[controlName] = new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});
      this.userForm.addControl(controlName, this.formCtls[controlName]);
      const idx = itm["value"].length-1;
      this.formCtls[controlName].valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
        itm["value"][idx]=val;
        this.renderDataArray();
      });
```